# How to have an index.html and index.php together

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, website

I need to upload a file called index.html alongside my index.php (please don't ask why) Is there way to leave everything as it is and serve the index.html page only if they request it with its specific url? (mysite.com/index.html)

I'm behind an apache server, I can modify the .htaccess or the virtual host if necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the default document by adding or modifying the following line in the .htaccess file in that directory.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```